Windows/Android Firefox + extensions failing recaptcha enterprise v3 attestations
I have Google Cloud Firebase Functions (onCall functions using firebase functions v2) with enableAppCheck: true that occasionally (~5% of users) return a 401 unauthorized error when called from my react front-end (which uses AppCheck successfully in the vast majority of cases).
Edit (again):
I've been able to narrow this down. I'm 99% sure it's certain browser/extension combos failing the recaptcha enterprise v3 attestation, which then results in no app check token, hence the failures. At least the vast majority of failures are coming from Android/Windows Firefox users.
A Windows Firefox user was able to consistently reproduce the issue as long as the malwarebytes browser guard extension was enabled. After disabling that extension, it worked fine. I haven't been able to do extensive Android Firefox testing, but at least some of the failures are coming from Android Firefox with the uBlock Origin extension.
It has definitely failed for multiple people with older versions of android with firefox and uBlock Origin, but a test with a new version of android and that combo worked fine.

the issue is not App Check token TTL
the issue is not related to Firebase Auth, which I don't use

An example of a log entry for a failing request (with a few irrelevant fields removed):
{
  "insertId": "redacted",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "POST",
    "requestUrl": "https://us-central1-redacted.cloudfunctions.net/redacted",
    "requestSize": "667",
    "status": 401,
    "responseSize": "285",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0",
    "remoteIp": "redacted",
    "referer": "https://redacted.com/",
    "serverIp": "redacted",
    "latency": "0.007421642s",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "configuration_name": "redacted",
      "project_id": "redacted",
      "revision_name": "redacted-00012-pur",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "service_name": "redacted"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-11-27T17:31:09.354872Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
    "instanceId": "redacted"
  },
}

I did some debugging with enableAppCheck temporarily set to false, and I saw in a number of cases that the app check token did indeed come in as undefined (request.app was undefined, while in the vast majority of cases it correctly includes token).
Also note that the front-end code never hits the logWarn in this listener:
  onTokenChanged(appCheck, (tokenResult) => {
    if (tokenResult.error) {
      logWarn('AppCheck token error', { error: tokenResult.error });
    } else {
      log('AppCheck token refreshed');
    }

